# How to link Vue frontend to Nodejs backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Hello this is my first time using Node js server in a project and I am trying to use a contact form that communicates with a Node.js server to send an email using the SendGrid API.

What I don't know is how to connect my Vue.js frontend with your Node.js backend and how can I configure the base url for my server? Please help, thanks in advance.

This is my server js.

```
const express = require('express'); const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

const port = 3000; const token = process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY;

const app = express();

sgMail.setApiKey(token);

//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O14qnICsIeQ

app.use( express.json() )

app.post('/send-email', async (req,res) => { 


    const { name, email, subject, message } = req.body;
    
    const msg = {
        to: 'mymail@gmail.com',
        from: 'mymail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Contact Form Submission',
        text: `Name: ${name}\nEmail: ${email}\nSubject: ${subject}\nMessage: ${message}`
        }

    if (!msg) {
        res.status(418).send( {message: 'We need a message!'})
    }

    try {
        await sgMail.send(msg);
        res.status(200).send({ message: 'Email sent successfully' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'An error occurred while sending the email' });
    }

})

app.listen(port, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Something went wrong ', error)
    } else {
        console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port)
    } })
```

And the function I call from ContactForm.vue

```
async sendEmail() {
      console.log(this.email);
      console.log(this.subject);
      console.log(this.message);

      const response = await fetch("/send-email", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: this.name,
          email: this.email,
          subject: this.subject,
          message: this.message,
        }),
      });

      const result = response;
      console.log(result);
    }
```

Comment: I guess your vue and node don't run on the same domains/ports ?

Comment: fetch doesn't have a base URL option.  You may be thinking of [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults).  With fetch you should use the absolute URL, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/send-email` or whatever domain/port your nodejs server runs on.